# visual studio for mac couldn't create .net core app

Tags: visual-studio

Today,I installed vs for mac, my OS have already installed .net core 1.0.0, today I installed a new version 1.1.
But after had created a .net core project, I built and run it. However, it reported an error:

[image]

So what should I do?

Now,I uninstalled .netCore1.0.0, but the error was still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the `.csproj` and update it set the `TargetFramework = My current version`,`.NETCore.app>Version = My current version`, `Microsoft.NET.Sdk>Version=My current version`.Now,It works well.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <Version>1.0.0-preview2-1-003177</Version>
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the version in your `project.json` file and run `dotnet-restore` to restore alle tools and dependencies in your project. 
Have a look at [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMysteryOfDotnetWatchAndMicrosoftNETCoreAppVersion110preview100110000WasNotFound.aspx) blog for more information

Comment: But there was no `project.json` in the project.

Comment: I created the project via vs4mac, but there was really no `project.json` .

Comment: That is strange. `project.json` is how NETCore handles your runtime frameworks, dependencies, compilation etc.

Comment: I've just seen that "vs4mac>project>options>build>general>TargetFramework: .NetCoreApp 1.0 (Not installed)"   Maybe vs4mac can't recognize .NetCore1.1, so when I created .net core project, it couldn't create a full .net core project.

Comment: The newest release: Use `.csproj` instead of `project.json' .

Answer (score 0):

You have installed:

- Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0
- Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.0

But your new project target version 1.0.1.

You can install version 1.0.1, or change in your project version you target to one of already installed versions.